# Using stripe.js with dj-stripe

Tags: django, stripe-payments

I'm using django and I want to integrate stripe using the abstraction layer dj-stripe.

From what I understand from the documentation, ElementJs with Payment Intent is the preferred way to allow users to enter their payment details. see https://dj-stripe.dev/stripe_elements_js/

However, there is no documentation on how to connect dj-stripe with stripe.js. The first step of the usage documentation in dj-stripe already assumes payment methods have been connected (https://dj-stripe.dev/usage/subscribing_customers/). I looked through the code of dj-stripe and it seems to have Payment Intent classes, but I can't figure out how to use them.

How can I generate a client secret for customers created in dj-stripe that can then be used in stripe.js? (Or if I'm not on the right path, what should I do instead to allow adding payment details to be used in dj-stripe)

Answer (score -1):

dj-stripe is a Python backend framework, and theoretically it should work with any frontend including pure stripe.js. You should follow [Stripe official Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements) and adapt. They also have an [example project in Python](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/quickstart?lang=python) (not Django though).